# How to test for significant differences among percent increases between two unbalanced samples from each of 10 treatments?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, unbalanced-classes, glmm, percentage

I am trying to figure out how best to analyse fruit weight data from an experiment involving samples of both open-pollinated and unpollinated fruit from each of 10 different pollination treatments.

I had expected the unpollinated fruit from each treatment to be similar in terms of fruit weight because the growing conditions were expected to be similar across all treatments. However, as it turned out, there was just as much variation in the unpollinated fruits as there was among the open-pollinated fruit from each treatment.

Therefore, in order to account for what appears to be variation in the growing conditions, I'm thinking the best option would be to compare the percent increase in fruit weight between the unpollinated and the heavier open-pollinated fruit from each treatment, and see if there are significant differences in this percentage increase across the 10 treatments.

The difficulty is that the samples of open-pollinated and unpollinated fruit from each treatment are unbalanced (i.e., there are different and inconsistent numbers of open-pollinated and unpollinated fruits from each treatment) and the fruit were randomly sampled, so there is no way to relate the weight value from one open-pollinated fruit to one of the unpollinated fruits. Thus, it wouldn't make sense to calculate the difference in weight between an individual unpollinated fruit and a corresponding open-pollinated fruit because no such correlation exists between the samples from a single treatment.

Is there a statistical test (e.g., some form of GLM or GLMM?) that could take into account the variation in fruit weights among both open-pollinated and unpollinated fruits from each treatment and then assess whether the improvements in fruit weight between unpollinated and open-pollinated fruits differed significantly across the 10 treatments?